# Please let me sync interesting & ignored tags between sites

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-watching

I'm not interested in "windows", "windows-7", "windows-vista", "iphone", "java", etc etc etc on stackoverflow.com.  Not surprisingly, I'm not interested in those on serverfault.com or superuser.com, either.

It would be swell if I could sync my tags, both interesting and ignored, across all the sites.

Comment: Note: tags themselves are not always in sync between the Trilogy sites.

Answer (score 3):

Each site is significantly different in what the tags represent. On StackOverflow, `iphone` generally refers to programming an iPhone. On SuperUser, `iphone` probably refers to troubleshooting problems with your iPhone. On Serverfault, `iphone` probably refers to getting iPhones to properly work with the corporate infrastructure.

These 3 connotations are so different, that there really isn't any reason that they should be transferable between sites.

Comment: I don't care about iphone on any of the three sites.  I don't care about programming the iphone, troubleshooting problems with the iphone, or getting the iphone to work in a corporate infrastructure.  Same goes for Windows.

I'm not suggesting that all three sites should use the same tags.  I'm asking for capability to sync them up, just like I can sync my user info.