# Show me other people's tag sets or favorited tags on their profile?

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching, tags

Show me other people's tag sets or favorited tags on their profile?  We already pretty well show all the other information, including favorites, can we show their tag sets? This would also apply to the profiles on the SE network profile as well.

There are reasons for wanting to see this, including "Oh, I want to follow that too".

Comment: See this other unpopular related request [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54631/make-public-interesting-and-ignored-tags).  I have no idea why people think all that other stuff should be public, and this shouldn't be, but in the words of Garth, "We Fear Change".

Answer (score 3):

But why?

It's pretty obvious which tags I'm active in. Look:
[image: My user tags page]

The blue ones are some of the tags I follow. The red ones are somewhat, err, surprising outcomes. Strange what people will tag questions with...

I don't follow these tags because someone else does. I follow these tags because this is my skill set, or I'm interested in learning, or whatever it is. Not because someone else follows them.

So, how is following [c](/questions/tagged/c) going to help you, if you write [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) all day? Moreover, what interest or use is it to you that Jon Skeet follows [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)? Or I follow [linux](/questions/tagged/linux)?

Comment: This doesn't show you the ones that you actively follow. What if you followed [tag:wpf-toolkit] or [tag:xpath-expression] only because you wanted to see if anyone posted to those tags for future questions, I would have no way of knowing that. We show favorites, which are an un-useful on-their-own collection of knowledge to have about a person, and on the network-profile we show similar stats such as their subscriptions, so why shouldn't we show this? It's not intended to _particularly influence_ someone, it's just to show what they do have. (cont)

Comment: (cont) Just because you have 47 in [tag:assembly] does that mean you follow it? I don't think so.

Comment: A fair point. There is no guarantee I'm following assembly, but ok, let's assume for a moment I'm following xpath-expression. What benefit does knowing that give anyone else, in terms of the Q&A experience?

Comment: What point does knowing anything about their voting history, or what they've favorited, helps in the Q&A process?