# Optionally Include Favorite and Ignored Tags in User Profiles

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, flair, ignored-tags, tag-watching

There is a lot of good information that can be gleaned about a person if you could see their "Favorite Tags" and their "Ignored Tags."  You would see what topics are relevant to the person's interests and what the person has virtually no interest in.  There was a [related post here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54631/make-public-interesting-and-ignored-tags) that talked about the SO data dump, which I know nothing about, and I see it got pretty poor reception.  So I'm going out on a limb here and saying that I would like to see these tags be *optionally* a part of a user's profile if the user *opts into* showing this information.  I understand the privacy aspects, and am in no way suggesting that this information be shown by default.

Next time someone asks me what programming topics I am interested in, it would be really nice if I could just point them to my StackOverflow user profile which would give them a great sense of my interests and disinterests at a glance based off of those tags.  I could even see a user wanting a piece of "valuable flair {tm}" generated out of their tag clouds for general posting.

I admit there is probably less value in the "Ignored Tags" then there are in the "Favorite Tags." I'm guessing most users have less "Favorite" than "Ignored" tags, and for profile space considerations, exposing just the user's "Favorite Tags" might be sufficient.

Comment: I would imagine that there would be a lot of duplication between "Favorite Tags" and the tags that you actively participate in. Those tags are already displayed at the bottom of your profile, along with your score (for both questions and answers) in each respective tag. I don't really know why more information than that needs to be public.

Comment: @Cody Gray  That's a very good and valid point.  That tag cloud demonstrates activity, while what I was talking about was more general interests, which I could just as easily add to my "Bio" section.  Incorporating the use of tags would only help if you were going to cross-link to other "similar" users.  My idea doesn't have much new value after all I guess.