# What are the most ignored tags on Stack Overflow (or any Stack Exchange site)?

Tags: discussion, tags, statistics, ignored-tags

There is the option to ignore tags on any Stack Exchange site. Questions with these tags do not appear on the landing page for that user. I was wondering what would be the most ignored tags. Is there anywhere a statistic about that?

Comment: I'm willing to bet that before it was removed, [homework] was amongst the most ignored tags.

Comment: I actually subscribed to [homework] before it was removed

Comment: @raam Get out of here, heathen :P

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I see myself out

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54631/make-public-interesting-and-ignored-tags

Comment: Ohh tanks, I think I did not found it because of all the downvotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I was wondering what would be the most ignored tags. Is there anywhere a statistic about that?

I don't think it is possible for us anyhow. Because there is no such information available either in [tags page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) or in [specific tag page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info).

Also looking at [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/), in the `Tags` table only following fields available:

```
Id             int
TagName        nvarchar (25)
Count          int
ExcerptPostId  int
WikiPostId     int
```

And obviously it should not be in `Users` table. So it is not possible to find out such information. Only Employees of SE can give information about it IMO.