# Apply "Favorite Tags" to all SE profiles automatically

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching, profile-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please let me sync interesting & ignored tags between sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48631/please-let-me-sync-interesting-ignored-tags-between-sites)

I'd like favorite tags added on one SE site to be added automatically on my other SE profiles.  Is this possible?

Comment: As mentioned in the duplicate, each site has its own tags so such thing is quite pointless.

Comment: The point is that many sites share tags, so why go to every profile and add all the same tags?

Comment: Because `[java]` on Stack Overflow and `[java]` on Seasoned Advice aren't the same.

Comment: @PopularDemand good example.  See also my answer regarding `indexing`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have something in place that might satisfy you already - global Stack Exchange filters.

To create such filter, first go to the ["My Filter"](https://stackexchange.com/filters) page on Stack Exchange main site. In that page choose "Just questions tagged with the `________`  tag" and on "All Sites" - add as many rules as the numbers of favorite tags, name your filter and Save. The screen should look like this:

[image: screenshot]

You can even choose to get daily email with all the results.

Comment: This is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 4):

**This is a bad idea.**   Even if the name of a tag is consistent between sites, it could mean different things on different places!

Take, for instance, [indexing](/questions/tagged/indexing):

- On SO it refers to all sorts of data access techniques
- On DBA.SE it refers to database indexing strategies
- On Serverfault it refers to search techniques using existing software
- On programmers.se it refers to search algorithms
- On webapps it refers to tagging and searching
- On Writers.se it refers to building indexes in the backs of books

There's no way to resolve all these, and this is just one example.  I'm sure there are dozens of tags that mean something different on every site they are present on.  Setting a network-wide definition per tag won't work either, since that takes away the autonomy of individual sites to set their own culture.

Automatically linking favorited tags between sites will just cause issues.  Shadowizard has a good alternative using the global filters.